# Searchable RecyclerView inside BottomSheetDialogFragment that stays expanded and does not wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

My app has a BottomSheetDialogFragment which displays list of countries with RecyclerView. When user types in the EditText bottomsheet shrinks in size so as to wrap content. What can I do to make BottomSheet remain the same and not shrink in height. I could not find anything similar on SO, closest thing I got was this article:
https://medium.com/@oshanm1/how-to-implement-a-search-dialog-using-full-screen-bottomsheetfragment-29ceb0af3d41

Can someone explain why this shrinking happens, why the article uses 2 LinearLayouts nested inside each other and provide solution to this problem with thorough explanation?
Here is xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilSearchCountries"
    style="@style/ReBankTIL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rtvCountry"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_search" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/tieSearchCountries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvCountries"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tilSearchCountries" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have you set the layout height to match_parent in your xml?

Comment: yes, I have tried match parent and 0dp both in parent layout and in RecyclerView itself.

Comment: okay if you could share your XML code it would help me to answer

Comment: as you are referring to that article use nested linear layout it will work. also, bottom sheets are implemented with coordinator layout as parent layout. but using bottomsheet behaviour works with the linear layout

Comment: I already made it work that way, with nested constraintlayouts. I wanted someone to provide detailed explanation why the layout keeps shrinking and if there is other way to achieve full length bottom sheet without nested layouts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226598/discussion-between-vatsal-kesarwani-and-nkhar).

Comment: @nkhar kindly share your constraintlayouts sample please. facing same issues